# How to fix set the environment variable Asymptote Ghostscript?

Tags: installing, asymptote, ghostscript

I have problem about install Asymptote and I fail to running file .asy like this error:

[image: Ghostscript dont install my computer]

How to fix location specifies the of Ghostscript and there are simple way to fix it ?

Comment: Is ghostscript [http://www.ghostscript.com/] installed on your computer?

Comment: Yes, i installed on my computer ?